# Assign multiple words as input from a CSV file without Quotes

Tags: powershell, permissions, csv, sp-online

I am running the below script to add users to SharePoint group in SPO sites:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$users= "" 
$users = import-csv D:\User.csv
foreach ($user in $users)
{
$groupname=$user.group
Add-SPOUser -Site $user.SiteURL -LoginName $user.UserEmailAddress -Group $groupname
Write-host "User added:" $user.SiteURL $groupname $user.UserEmailAddress
}
```

The input namely UserEmailAddress, SiteURL and Group are fetched from a csv file.

This script works fine if the group name is a single word without any space like Approvers, SiteOwners but if the group name has 2 or more words with spaces between them, the script displays the error "Group cannot be found"

I understood the issue and tried different approaches to fix it but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping $groupname in quotation marks? `-Group "$groupname"`

Comment: @RuneSperre yes, if i wrap $groupname within quotes, it is considering $groupname as text and not variable. Anything within the quotes is takes a plain text

Comment: Do you have this issue for all groups with multiple words name ?

Comment: No, variables are expanded inside strings. If you wanted to use $user.group directly you would have to type it as `"$($user.group)"` though. [Reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/)

Comment: @a1mery yes, i face same issue for any group with multiple words

Comment: @RuneSperre will try that and update

Comment: Another option would be to get the group id by `Get-SPOSiteGroup` first and then use the Id for that in `Add-SPOUser`. Unless that causes the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @RuneSperre for your solution. It worked. Below is the working script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$users= "" 
$users = import-csv D:\User.csv
foreach ($user in $users)
{
  Add-SPOUser -Site $user.SiteURL -LoginName $user.UserEmailAddress -Group "$($user.group)"
  Write-host "User added:" $user.SiteURL $groupname $user.UserEmailAddress
}
```